# issue with installing MediaWiki on Fedora

Tags: php, linux, installation, mediawiki, fedora

I'm trying to install MediaWiki on fedora 17

I've followed the following instructions [install guide](http://www.wikihow.com/Install-MediaWiki-on-Fedora).

I reached a stage where i'm supposed to configure MediaWiki on localhost/wiki page.

instead I get a page that specifies the files under that directory.

It seems that something is wrong with my php setttings/installation.

If you need me to post additional information please let me know.

Any ideas on how to resolve this issue?

---

Edit:
The following files are visible

```
[TXT]   api.php 12-Apr-2011 04:07   4.5K     
[DIR]   config/ 12-Jun-2012 12:58   -    
[DIR]   images/ 12-Jun-2012 12:58   -    
[TXT]   index.php   01-Jan-2010 23:09   4.2K     
[TXT]   opensearch_desc.php 21-Mar-2009 18:48   3.0K     
[DIR]   skins/
```

---

Thanks now the php pages' source is displayed  in it the following message appear

```
* This is the main web entry point for MediaWiki.
 *
 * If you are reading this in your web browser, your server is probably
 * not configured correctly to run PHP applications!
```

any ideas how to configure that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which directory's content do you see? Can you add the list of files under that directory as you see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try adding a

```
.htaccess
```

file to the directory you see, with:

```
Options -Indexes
```

in it, to disable directory listing.

EDIT:

Take a look at the httpd.conf file in your local Apache folder. You need to modify the DirectoryIndex value to display index.php also:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm
```

EDIT 2:

For running install script, you need to make
the 'config' directory writable by the webserver/apache user.

```
chmod a+w config
```

restart apache with:

```
service httpd restart
```

then reload the page.

HTH

Comment: Thank you very much, this took me forward. now the php file source is displayed. edited answer